# issue with gravity in andengine android

Tags: android, andengine, uigravitybehavior

I attempting to write simple game that include player sprite and obstacles.
I have implemented a physics world with gravity. I would like when player sprite falling it will be near the obstacle where it falling from, but with gravity the the sprite falling in diagonal and not straight down.

```
mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
...

public Player(PhysicsWorld world, final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion,
        final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager)
{
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);

    mPlayerDeff = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0);

    mVertexBuffer = pVertexBufferObjectManager;
    mBoardManager = BoardManager.getInstance();
    mDirection = DIRECTION_RIGHT;

    mWorld = world;

    mBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, mPlayerDeff);
    mWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, mBody, true, false));

}
```

[image: current state and wanted state]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set mass data to your body:

```
MassData mass = new MassData();
mass.mass = 10; // in kilograms

mBody.setMassData(mass);
```